# Scraping values of i and span tag that are inside of a p tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape the release date and number of downloads from the below code

```html
<p><i class="no-flip-over">Release date</i> : <span class="no-flip-over">2022-06-02</span></p>
<p><i class="no-flip-over">Downloads</i> : <span class="no-flip-over" data-times-funtouch="">703</span></p>
```

Here's is my function to scrape it

```
def phone_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    sp = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    data = {
        "Release_Date" : sp.select_one('i.no-flip-over').text.strip().replace('\n', ' '),
        "Downloads" : sp.select_one('i.no-flip-over').text.strip().replace('\n', ' '),
    }
    print(data)


phone_data('https://www.vivo.com/in/support/upgradePackageData?id=132')
```

Here's my output:

```py
{'Release_Date': '', 'Downloads': ''}
```

I am unable to see the values besides the keys in the dictionary

Comment: You are selecting a `<i>` tag with the class `no-flip-over` while the data seems to be in a `span`.  Also you are using the same selector for both release date and downloads while you probably want to get them from different elements.

Comment: I tried using span tag and here's the output

{'Release_Date': 'new', 'Downloads': 'new'}

I used the same selector because the website I'm scraping from uses same class for both of the values

Comment: Take a loot at the [available CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and find a group that *uniquely* identifies the items you are looking for. Most likely you are matching some other element on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution provided by @QHarr I would also recommend in fact you know exactly about the facts to scrape, so this is just an alternative that comes from the other site and may fits title of the question a bit better*

Simply iterate all specs and create a dict with key value pair:

```
data = dict(e.text.split(' : ',1) for e in sp.select('.msg h1 ~ p:has(i+span)'))
```

Sure you will scrape more as these two facts, but also get a very good overview about all the `.keys()` maybe there are some with typos, ... and you can pick an adjust in post processing.

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def phone_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    sp = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    data = dict(e.text.split(' : ',1) for e in sp.select('.msg h1 ~ p:has(i+span)'))
    return data

phone_data('https://www.vivo.com/in/support/upgradePackageData?id=132')
```

```
{'Release date': '2022-02-25',
 'File size': '1.87M',
 'Downloads': '3545',
 'Support system': 'Windows'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `:-soup-contains` to target in addition to the class, as well as remove the span as you need that as the adjacent element. You can use an adjacent sibling combinator to move from the element initially matched by class and  `:-soup-contains` to the adjacent span.

You then avoid repeating the same info twice and can remove the calls to `strip()` and `replace()`.

```
def phone_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    sp = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    data = {
        "Release_Date" : sp.select_one('.no-flip-over:-soup-contains("Release date") + span').text,
        "Downloads" : sp.select_one('.no-flip-over:-soup-contains("Downloads") + span').text,
    }
    print(data)


phone_data('https://www.vivo.com/in/support/upgradePackageData?id=132')
```